# Class size instantiated in a sub-function, i.e. is this a good time to use new?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I want to create a vector of data, but I want to both set it's size and fill its elements in a sub-function. Is this an appropriate time to use the new operator? Is there a better way to do it? It seems like an appropriate time, but I'm hesitant because of [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/in-c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible)

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> *array1;
    vector<double> *array2;
    OtherArgs otherArgs;
    FillArrays(array1,array2,otherArgs);
    //Do other stuff 
    delete array1;
    delete array2;
}

void FillArrays(vector<double> *&array1, vector<double> *&array2, OtherArgs &otherArgs)
{
    int size=GetSize(otherArgs);
    array1 = new vector<double>(size);
    array2 = new vector<double>(size);
    //Other code to fill the arrays
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just return a `tuple`/`pair` of `vector`s?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using new but it doesn't seem like you need to.

Comment: @K-ballo: You should write that up as an answer. The pair<vector> solution is easier to use ("fluent"), and easier to understand, and if you're using C++11, or a C++98 compiler with a good optimizer, it will produce code with the same performance as JaredPar's answer. Of course if any of the compilers you need to support end up copying the contents of the vectors (and the time taken to do that makes a difference), then you can fall back to JaredPar's answer as an optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of reasons why the original sample is troublesome

- The code leaks memory in the face of an exception because the `delete` calls aren't protected
- If `FillArrays` is passed a non-NULL `vectory<double>` value it will leak memory because it didn't delete the previous value.  It couldn't reliably call `delete` even if it wanted to because the value may have been stack allocated.

The easiest way to do this is to just declare the values on the stack and pass them by reference that way.

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> array1;
    vector<double> array2;
    OtherArgs otherArgs;
    FillArrays(array1,array2,otherArgs);
    //Do other stuff 
}

void FillArrays(vector<double> &array1, vector<double> &array2, OtherArgs &otherArgs)
{
    int size=GetSize(otherArgs);
    //Other code to fill the arrays
}
```

The `vector<T>` will initialize themselves to an empty list when declared in this manner.  The `FillArrays` method can then populate them as necessary.

Comment: +1 - this way you can still do `array1 = vector<double>(size);` or similar.

Comment: Thanks moooeeeep and JaredPar

Answer (score 3):

No, this is a specifically bad use of `new`.

If you must use `new` and `delete`<sup>1</sup>, use them as bookends. The delete expression should be in a logically consistent context with the new expression.

So, if you `new` in a c-tor, you should `delete` in the d-tor. If you `new` in an allocation function, you should `delete` in a deallocation function. The two calls should be arranged in an way that makes it obvious that one starts an operation and the other finishes it.

This implies that the call to `new` and `delete` should exist in the same layer in a functional or object hierarchy.  Specifically, `new` and `delete` should be seen as implementation details, and not as part of the API contract.<sup>2</sup>

In your case, the new and delete are in entirely distinct contexts. `new` is inside the implementation, while `delete` is called for in the client. This *will* lead to programming errors.

Beyond that, the non-new version of your code (creating empty vectors in `main`, and passing them by reference) is simpler, easier to read, and more exception-friendly than the `new` version.

No, this is not a good example of when to use `new`. It is, however, an excellent example of when *not* to.

---

<sup>1 You hardly ever **need** to use `new` and `delete`. If you need dynamic allocation, just let containers keep copies of your objects.</sup>

<sup>2 `std::shared_ptr`, et al, violate this rule -- the `new` and `delete` are specifically part of the contract. This is probably OK, since pointer manipulation is their reason for existence. But SO has seen its share of bugs about storing a non-`new` pointer in `shared_ptr`.</sup>